# In what case would special characters such as "ÄÖÜß" be encoded into entities and then decoded into "ƒ÷‹S"?

Tags: php, decode, encode, html-entities

I am stumped as to why this would occur. 
If I enter text such as "ÄÖÜß" (that gets stored into the DB as such) but is then converted to html entities, when I run

```
$html['address_array'] = array_map("html_entity_decode", $html['address_array']);
```

This converts the html entities "ÄÖÜß" into "ƒ÷‹S", rather than "ÄÖÜß" which is the desired output.

Comment: Maybe the default encoding doesn't match the encoding of your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a text encoding problem. The most likely possibility is that your text is being interpreted as Mac OS Roman -- `ÄÖÜß` encoded as ISO8859-1 is `C4 D6 DC DF`; after decoding as Mac OS Roman, that comes out as `ƒ÷‹ﬂ`. The last character is different from your sample, but it's close enough that I suspect it's a match.

Pass an encoding to `html_entity_decode` -- ideally UTF-8 -- and make sure that your page is using an appropriate character set. Since you're using `array_map`, passing an encoding is a little awkward; if you're using a modern version of PHP, I'd recommend:

```
$html["address_array"] = array_map(
    function($x) {
        return html_entity_decode($x, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    },
    $html["address_array"]
);
```